# MATLAB: lossless viewing of images in double format

Tags: image, matlab, double

I'm trying to view some images that are currently doubles. If I use imtool/imshow I get an image that looks like a binary with only the darkest portion of the image as black and the rest white. If I move the cursor over the image I see a wide range of double values. I can view the image fine if I use:

```
 imtool(uint8(image))
```

but I'm concerned that I'm losing information doing this. Is there a way to display the double without converting it to a format where I loose info?

Comment: use `imagesc` not `imshow`

Comment: can i save it in a viewable lossless way? 32bit tif maybe? I can only open the original file in MATLAB, hoping to write the doubles as something imageJ can open and use without loss